# How does RealVNC Enterprise Know My System Credential?

Tags: passwords, windows

After the installation of RealVNC on a Windows computer, the default login username and password via VNC is the same as the system username and password. Can anyone tell me how RealVNC can access such information? Isn't such information supposed to be encrypted and unaccessible except Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It does NOT. Allowing you to login using your system credentials does not necessarily mean that RealVNC knows them. It means RealVNC asks the OS to do the authentication for it. Your password is never saved on your hard drive and even your OS is not aware of it, it's the hash of your password that is saved and used to verify that you are who you claim to be. The hash can't be reversed and your password can't be retrieved by RealVNC or any other program.

Answer (score -1):

Some applications, by their very nature, require system and administrative rights.  Any remote desktop service must dig deep into the internals of the underlying OS, so it's not surprising that it must also acquire system and/or administrative rights.  Those rights include permission to access to user credential information, especially since the nature of the application is to regulate access to the system via user authentication.

Comment: Remote desktop software does not require deep internal access to the OS. Nor does it need administrative access.